# Xaml interactions not working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am working on a Windows Store App (Windows 8.1) and I am using a searchbox like this:

```
<SearchBox x:Name="SearchText" QueryText="{Binding QueryText, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="QuerySubmitted">
            <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SearchCommand}" />
      </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
  </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</SearchBox>
```

This is working fine in Windows 8.1, but I was just testing a preview version of Windows 10 and found out the SearchCommand is not firing. The QuerySubmitted event fires correctly when I add an eventhandler in the code behind, so it looks like the binding does not work. Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Comment: I don't think it's all Xaml Interactions as I've found others (like Button.Click) are working. However I'm running into the same problem with SearchBox.QuerySubmitted, even tried just a normal event hookup to codebehind is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 <SearchBox>
                <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="QueryChanged">
                        <interactivity:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TxtSearchCommand}"></interactivity:InvokeCommandAction>
                    </interactivity:EventTrigger>
                </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>

            </SearchBox>
```